# Compare open generic parameter with open generic interface type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Is it possible (in `c#`) to compare an open generic parameter e.g. `T` in:

```
public void CompareMethod<T>() { ... }
```

with the type of an open generic interface (or class)?
Here is an example interface:

```
public interface IExample<T> { }
```

And then somehow inside the method compare them like this:

```
public void CompareMethod<T>()
{
    if (typeof(IExample<>) == typeof(T))
    {
        //execute
    }
}
```

The `if` body won't execute when called the method like this:

```
CompareMethod<IExample<object>>();
```

It is *important* that I don't know in advance what closed types will be entered in the open generic parameter of the `CompareMethod`.

Comment: Why are you using a generic type parameter if you need to compare its `T` parameter? Could you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I agree with @YuvalItzchakov, This sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm using this in a WPF application with the MVVM pattern applied. I have a service which shows windows/dialogs by supplying the type of the ViewModel. These ViewModels implement some interfaces. I've assigned a responsibility to this service that it also does some additional work on some of these viewmodels. But that additional work is only applied on a selective set of interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` on `T` to be able to compare it with `IExample<>`:

```cs
public void CompareMethod<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T).IsGenericType && 
        typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IExample<>)) {
    {
        //execute
    }
}
```